# loop condition in quicksort

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, quicksort

consider the below code for quick sort

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printArray(int *A, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", A[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int partition(int A[], int low, int high)
{
    int pivot = A[low];
    int i = low + 1;
    int j = high;
    int temp;

    do
    {   
     while (A[i] <=pivot )
       {
        i++;
       }
        while (A[j] > pivot)
        {
            j--;
        }

        if (i < j)
        {
            temp = A[i];
            A[i] = A[j];
            A[j] = temp;
        }
    } while (i < j);

    // Swap A[low] and A[j]
    temp = A[low];
    A[low] = A[j];
    A[j] = temp;
    return j;
}

void quickSort(int A[], int low, int high)
{
    int partitionIndex; // Index of pivot after partition

    if (low < high)
    {
        partitionIndex = partition(A, low, high); 
        quickSort(A, low, partitionIndex - 1);  // sort left subarray 
        quickSort(A, partitionIndex + 1, high); // sort right subarray
    }
}

int main()
{
    
    int A[] = {9, 4, 4, 8, 7, 5, 6};
    n =7;
    printArray(A, n);
    quickSort(A, 0, n - 1);
    printArray(A, n);
    return 0;
}
```

I have doubt in do while loop in partition function. for the given value of input of array the loop below should have become infinite or may result in undefine behavior because there is no value in array which is greater than 9 and i will keep on increasing and will exceed size of array the loop should have shown some error but the code is running fine why??

```
while (A[i] <= pivot)
        {
            i++;
        }
```

Comment: If there is no `j` for which `A[j] > pivot`, then that `while` loop will never run.

Comment: I don't understand why do you exchange `A[low]` and `A[j]` at the end of the partition functon. Can you edit the question explaining it?  (or add a comment here explaining)